# Prove that if $\sigma(x) \le 2x$ and $n|x$ where $n\neq x$, then $\sigma(n)<2n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

> Prove that if $\sigma(x) \le 2x$ and $n|x$ where $n\neq x$, then $\sigma(n)<2n$.

So far I tried that if $n|x$, then $\sigma(n)<\sigma(x)\le 2x$, but $2n<2x$, so this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Write $x = kn$ for some $k>1$.  Can you see why $\sigma(x) \ge k \sigma(n)$?  (Hint: find an appropriate one-to-one mapping from divisors of $n$ to divisors of $x$).  Can you see why the inequality is in fact strict?  (Hint: find at least one divisor of $x$ that isn't covered by the previous mapping.)

Comment: What do you know about $\dfrac{\sigma(k)}{k}$?